# @Autowired beans not loading after using beans:profiles in spring 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3, autowired

I have used `beans:profiles` in my xml like this:

```
    <beans profile="dev">
        <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.internal.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.internal.username}" />
        </bean>
   </beans>
```

I've set the `spring.active.profiles` in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>dev</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

My code structure is like this:

```
//controller
@Controller 
public class MyController {
  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;
  ....
}

//service implementation
@Service("myservice")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  @Autowired
  DBService dbService;
} 

//db service
@Service("dbservice)
public class DBServiceImpl implements DbService {
  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource (Datasource ds) { 
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
  }
}
```

Error:

> Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private MyService
>   MyController.myService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>
> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dbService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   DBServiceImpl.setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource); nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

Comment: and what is the nested exception? :)

Comment: updated :) It seems like bean isn't being created for datasource. But i've set the active profile in web.xml...

Comment: have you tried with giving public access? 'public DBService dbService;'

Comment: unfortunately yes. that made no difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess it that you are using profile in DispatcherServlet context, while DataSource is likely located in the root application context.

See [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)

**update**: try using context-params (taken from [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-31-environment-profiles)):

```
<context-param>
<param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
<param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: hmmm so I should set the profile in application context? how do I do that?

Comment: I was following this blog post and thats how they were doing it: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Comment: I think you might be right, because when I explicitly use `@Service("dbService) @Profile("dev") public class DBServiceImpl...` I at least don't get datasource not found exception.. But I this won't be my ideal solution. I much rather set active profile in application context

Comment: Hmmm I'm reading https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9035 they agree that this is by design, but it doesn't seem that they post a solution.

Comment: or maybe I'm mistaken. because if I intentionally give profile a bad name like: `@Service("dbService) @Profile("devasdfsfd") public class DBServiceImpl..` even then I don't get datasource not found exception...

Comment: `@Autowired` always wires by-type so it doesn't matter how you name your beans in this case.

Comment: wow, that works!! how do I buy you a beer? :) thanks for all the help!