# Exception while configuring MongoDb with Spring-Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Getting this error while application run. I am using MongoDb with spring-data. Also, i am using spring boot.

```
[org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:117) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:108) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:68) [spring-boot-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:182) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource              org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) [spring-   beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/ DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for    database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) [spring-    beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) [spring-   beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the     classpath.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
... 48 more
```

I have below lines in my application.properties file.

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=127.0.0.1
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mongodb.Mongo
spring.data.mongodb.database=DigitalDiary
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
```

My Entity (Document), this class is in different package than main class.

```
@Document(collection = "blood_group_collection")
public class BloodGroup {

@Id
private String _id;
@Indexed(unique=true)
private String blood_group_type;

public BloodGroup(String blood_group_type) {
    super();
    this.blood_group_type = blood_group_type;
}

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public String getBlood_group_type() {
    return blood_group_type;
}

public void setBlood_group_type(String blood_group_type) {
    this.blood_group_type = blood_group_type;
}

}
```

My MongoRepository class. This is class is in different package than main class and entity (document) class.

```
public interface BloodGroupRepository extends    MongoRepository<BloodGroup, String>{

}
```

I have @EnableMongoRepositories("com.awt.mongo.repository") in main class.
I am not able to find any solution. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311603/autowired-beans-not-loading-after-using-beansprofiles-in-spring-3-1  The exception seems to be caused by auto wiring was not set properly

Comment: the root cause is : Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource    . Have a look at sprint documentation regarding configuration of data source : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Comment: I checked your given link but i am not able to find out the problem. Can you help to resolve this, I posted logs and classes too.

Comment: Is there anyone who can resolve my problem? I am stuck on this from 7 hrs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The exception was because of spring jpa. I removed spring-jpa dependency from pom.xml and it solved my problem. Thanks all for help and quick response.

Comment: It resolved my problem too, wondering what was the reason. Mongodb is configured by JPA is not?

Comment: Mongodb is configured by spring data

Answer (score 1):

I can see from your error that your data source is not correctly configured:

"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath."

I suspect the line that states:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mongodb.Mongo
```

is wrong - this looks like a JDBC driver, but as MongoDB is a NoSQL database its driver doesn't conform to the same standards.

The [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) suggests the following properties for MongoDB:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host= # the db host
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 # the connection port (defaults to 27107)
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # connection URL
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database=
spring.data.mongodb.username=
spring.data.mongodb.password=
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true # if spring data repository support is enabled
```

Comment: I removed spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mongodb.Mongo, still getting same exception. There is no username and password for my local mongoDb.

Comment: Is it still exactly the same error? Spring Exceptions contain a lot of information, and sometimes it's easy to miss the real error deep in the stack trace

Comment: Yes, i checked it again. Its same exception.

Comment: I don't think it should be trying to create a `javax.sql.DataSource` at all, this is not going to work with MongoDB. Do you have other database-related code in your application.properties?

Comment: No, i don't have any other db code in application.properties

Comment: My logs after removing spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mongodb.Mongo are same as it was before

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the MongoDB properties from application.properties? In the [Spring Boot / MongoDB example code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-mongodb/src/main/resources/application.properties), they don't have anything in the application.properties

Comment: Removed everything, still same exception.

Comment: I suggest you start a new empty project following the guidelines in the [Getting Started](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) documentation, to see if you can get a simple project working in your environment.

Comment: My problem was the configuration I had in application.properties. Commenting all these properties related to MongoDB, the embedded version was able to start and run the tests without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `<version>` tag in POM file, the problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following dependency

- JDBC dependency
- spring-jpa dependency

my issue was resolved when I removed both the dependency